# Error al usar yarn build para desplegar frontend de proyecto en Netlify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, terminal, deployment

buenas tardes. Mi nombre es Benjamin Castillo y estudio ing en informatica. Les comento la situacion que estoy teniendo. Realice un proyecto con el stack MERN, este proyecto es de un curso de udemy, el cual es el siguiente: https://www.udemy.com/course/web-personal-mern-full-stack-mongodb-express-react-node/

Al finalizar el proyecto este es desplegado la parte del server (backend) en Heroku y la parte del clien (frontend) en Netlify. Lo que es la parte del server a pesar de darme mini errores logre subirla a Heroku sin dificultad. Ahora, al momento de intentar subirlo a Netlify la parte del client me esta dando un error. Esto es al momento de crear la carpeta build para desplegar en netlify. ¿Que ocurre? Pues al momento de usar "yarn build" me genera el tipico mensaje predeterminado el cual menciona que se ha asumido que quiero desplegar el proyecto en "/" cuando en el package.json ya escribi la propiedad de "homepage" con el link que me brinda netlify. Tambien inclui en el public un archivo de _redirects y modifique el BrowserRouter de mi App.js de "react-router-dom" a HashRouter pero aun asi al hacer el yarn build sigue diciendome que se asume que el proyecto se esta desplegando en "/".

Pense que era un error de no haber hecho un commit en git antes del build pero tampoco pues he hecho commits para guardar los nuevos cambios del proyecto pero aun asi sigue diciendo lo mismo, adjunto fotos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor sube tu codigo no capturas de panta